# Как работать с parcel

Tags: java, android

Есть следующая структура:

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
```

Как написать Parcel для нее?

```
 @Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
 //Что тут написать?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parcel.writeTypedList(data);`

При этом класс Data также должен быть Parcelable.

Для считывания списка в creator'е нужно будет написать:

`data = parcel.createTypedArrayList(Data.CREATOR);`

Описания методов:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeTypedList(java.util.List%3CT%3E)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#createTypedArrayList(android.os.Parcelable.Creator%3CT%3E)

Рекомендую плагин Android Parcelable Code Generator для Android Studio.

P. S. Вместо того, чтобы с back-end отправлять структуру типа `{data: [...]}`, можно отправить `[...]`, а в Android принять как `ArrayList<Data>`.

Answer (score 1):

Если `Data implements Parcelable`, то можно использовать методы:
- `parcel.writeTypedList(data)` для записи
- `parcel.createTypedArrayList(Data.CREATOR)` для чтения
В [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) приведен полный список возможных методов